# I was redirecting to same login page again and again and it's not even authenticating the credentials

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

my login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login" media="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><be>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><be>
        <input type="Submit">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate




 # Create your views here.
 def homepage(request):
 return render(request, 'homepage.html')


def login(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
             auth.login(request, user)
             return redirect("/")
       else:
           messages.success(request,'password not matching')
           return redirect('home')
   else:
        return render(request,'login.html')

def registration(request): 

if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    confirmpassword = request.POST['confirmpassword']
    email = request.POST['email']

    if password==confirmpassword:
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Username Taken')
            return redirect('/registration')
        elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request, 'Email Taken')
            return redirect('/registration')
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, 
 password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
            user.save();
            print('user successfully created')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        messages.info(request,'password not matching')
        return redirect('/registration')
    return redirect('/')


else:
    return render(request, 'registration.html')
```

my urls.py:

```
 from django.urls import path

 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
      path('',views.homepage, name='homepage'),
      path('login',views.login, name='login'),
      path('registration',views.registration, name='registration'),
      ]
```

every single time this login page is redirecting to same login page, whether I enter wrong credentials or the right one, I think its not even verifying the credentials that whether they are right or wrong. please help me out.
please help me out.
please help me out.
please help me out.
please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You checked if there is a user with as username `'username'` and as password `'password'`, you do not use the `user` and `password` variables, but strings that *contain* `username` and `password` as *content*. You thus should use variables:

```
# not 'username' and 'password'
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

Comment: i had edited above urls(i had typed wrong here but not in my project)... now please review it again ...it is still redirecting to same page

Comment: @siddharthsoni: this is *not* part of the urls, but of the view, the login view.

Comment: @siddharthsoni: are you sure the user exists with the given credentials. How did you create the user? Note that Django does *not* store raw passwords, but hashed ones.

Comment: sorry again .. above i want to write views instead of urls

Comment: i had created some demo user through my registration page..and i had checked my postgres database they are created in the desired table

Comment: @siddharthsoni: but does it *hash* the password? Can you share the `register` view?

Comment: attached above in views file

Comment: @siddharthsoni: do you see the raw password in the database, or a hashed one (which has the form `algorithm$number$hash`)?

Comment: @siddharthsoni: then the password is not hashed. Did you change the code of registering after creating the user? As you can see this is the expected password format in the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords